# Monaco editor decorate range outside of line text

Tags: monaco-editor

I would like to highlight a block of text in monaco editor as squarish as possible, something looks like this:

[image: datagrip highlight]

However, it seems like decorations cannot be applied to columns that do not have actual value. I could only achieve something like this:

[image]

I tried passing range longer than the line length but it will be truncated to the end of line. Is there any option to configure this behaviour without padding empty spaces?

I have a simplified demo at https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.46.0#XQAAAALpAgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw1_DLRgmSaumWUF-TBOsVJ4S4FwfCDQb5-2uUHXTVAefbVSd9IzaZ_vv9VR9KugsKimARHSWlrTPOQHROITHxmBQo4t5-9nSBbItajHE3t2aXZpS3nBULwWyyBNLdhoC9HSNJ-ZY9uG0I1zBlGGD5VF8cZmF6NAMOefjmlgPrN48C9rz9oN9gohCNsUMZmxlxFkBsF6kgmZZ8Ea-Pxaz0T-e5DlAcN8ORV9wM8HeQB8hTk25VOEaE51X0i6xC5xng5h9jZ7Ks31zDI9uBxhSy0xgVbLZ3iu3bJIA5P0_qw3BmPCirZlGgc4OG2NX8hIrnuAjM3zL2lZpPNo8sbvkCDj8gs7zO-um2NBleq6RnG6w4Vx8B2YQ3BljwqgkMItatVCBA-YCBc8rLHMNKsHXPQsgu3j4BYaBWap0ZO7Skbj_PNf3faxUuXcdaMPjz68NxAElbCPx7wYmGrXBc3fxlMn44gvw7dhKNlVhHrIOgCM56hu8J7G7ML61_SL9qKOVJ0E6U0ZKSRppdTqQHp6wkIZ4bmIC_Oc8XKMo-0htUL2761ka_8h8zFPkARNagRYTxbpOKfw9___lng4c